# what functions should I include in my application?

Tags: c#, winforms, time-and-attendance

I want to define a time attendance system for government, and right now I am preparing a system requirement document, can someone give me some advices about what features/functions should I include in the system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ones that your customer asks for... not the ones that stackoverflow users might suggest :)

Answer (score 3):

```
public int MeaningOfLife
{
    get
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Charge for anything beyond that.